# How to get "Author of a project" from Gitlab webhooks

Tags: python, api, gitlab, webhooks

Basically, I am working on integration of **Gitlab** with my app. I am using webhook for subjected purpose. Everything is working fine. But, I am stuck on little part of getting name of **author** of particular project.

Here [Gitlab Events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#events) as one can see it doesn't provide author directly. And, I could have used key called **user** but it won't be wise, because logged in user could be collaborator or something else and author would be someone else.

Here is the little code, where I am trying:

```
project_data = payload['project']
    response = {
        'gitlab_id': project_data ['id'],
        'name': project_data ['name'],
        'url': project_data ['web_url'],
        #'author': ???
    }
    print(response)
```